# Is there an actively maintained replacement for Bookshelf.js?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

The most recent Bookshelf.js version is over two years old.

What is the recommended replacement?

Comment: Sequelize? TypeORM?

Comment: Thanks, but my question was more about potential drop-in replacements, so I don't have to rewrite everything.